# Is there a way to add custom apache site.conf with docker-compose and active it?

Tags: docker, apache, docker-compose, httpd.conf

I want use docker as backend after some years with LAMP, I'm using docker with docker-compose.

Here docker-compose.yml:

```yaml
services:
    php:
        image: php:8.0-apache
        container_name: php
        restart: always
        ports:
            - "80:80"
        volumes:
            - /var/www/docker/php:/var/www/html
            - ./conf:/etc/apache2/sites-available
        links:
            - db:db
    db:
        image: mysql
        container_name: db
        restart: always
        volumes:
            - ~/mysql:/var/lib/mysql
        ports:
            - "3306:3306"
        environment:
            - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=root
    admin:
        image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin
        container_name: admin
        ports:
            - "8080:80"
        links:
            - db:db
```

So I erase `/etc/apache2/sites-available` who already contain 000-default.conf with my local.dev.conf:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/
    ServerName local.dev
    <Directory /var/www/html/>
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

I put a basic index.php file in /var/www/html in container that displays 'test' but it only displays at `http://localhost` and I want it at `http://local.dev`

I saw there is a file `docker-php.conf` but how to change it cause erase 000-default.conf seems change nothing?

Comment: Did you add `127.0.0.1 local.dev` to your `hosts` file on your host machine? (on linux in `/etc/hosts`, on windows in `c:\windows\system32\drivers\etc\hosts`)

Comment: Hi, thanks for you comment, i'm working on linux and there is no `/etc/hosts` ... but the problem come from the container I think

Comment: I just tested your example and it was working to me (exept I had to remove line `Listen 80` from `local.dev.conf`)  so I' really suspecting that you didn't set route for `local.dev`. There should be host file in path `/etc/hosts`. What linux distro are you using?

Comment: I am using ubuntu focal fossa, `/etc/hosts` on my machine ?

Comment: Yes, `/etc/hosts` on your machine (ubuntu focal). Edit it as a `root` there should be line `127.0.0.1 localhost` which instructs your OS that `localhost` domain is alias for your PC.
You need to do the same for `local.dev` so your OS knows where it should look for it. Read more about it eg. here: https://supporthost.com/hosts-file/

Comment: ok it's done but there is no change, and shouldn't I add a2ensite command? And how my config work with container ?

Comment: Docker runs containers in isolated environment including network so if you want to access it from your host machine you have to map some port of your host machine to container port. `php:8.0-apache` listens on port `80` and in `docker-compose.yaml` you specified `ports: [ "80:80 ]` so it will map your system port `80` to container port `80`. Result is that you can access it using `http://127.0.0.1`. Thanks to default config in `/etc/hosts` you can also access it via `http://localhost`. By adding line `127.0.0.1 <something>` to `/etc/hosts` you can set another aliases, eg. wanted `local.dev`

Comment: By adding line `127.0.0.1 local.dev` to `hosts` file you are saying to your OS that if you want to access `http://local.dev` it shouldn't look for it somewhere on Internet but that  `local.dev` is name of your machine. Thus it will take a look what application is running on your PC on port `80` (because it's default port for `http`) and it will find out that it should forward your request to container `php:8.0-apache` (thanks to `ports: ["80:80"]` config in your `docker-compose.yaml`. The rest is up to container `apache` to correctly handle the request and provide desired response.

Comment: Thank you very much for these explanations, and indeed it seems that it works but now I have an error `ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED`
Thank you again I will update my question with your response

Comment: @MartinDendis Ok that work with `dev.local` but not `*.dev` => https://askubuntu.com/questions/1085776/connection-refused-for-apache-virtual-hosts-on-local-dev-setup
If you know why

Comment: Glad you were able to resolve your issue :) This might explain why `.dev` is not working: https://medium.engineering/use-a-dev-domain-not-anymore-95219778e6fd (I'm not using chrome so that might be why it was working for me... sry)